# If $I$ is a finitely generated semisimple left $R-$module, show that $I=Re$ for an idempotent $e \in I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $I$ be a left ideal in a semiprime ring $R$. If $I$ is a finitely generated semisimple left $R-$module, show that $I=Re$ for an idempotent $e \in I$.

Comment: See [here](https://books.google.ro/books?id=9v1AAm7xP-oC&pg=PA132&lpg=PA132&dq=%22finitely+generated%22+%22semisimple%22+%22ideal%22+idempotent+%22semiprime+ring%22&source=bl&ots=fCkYgawaKR&sig=Ouh5_6ru_elturMRNYLysLmdRGU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ruZZVe7vMML4ygOhpoHIDA&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=true), Lemma 14.5.

Comment: @user26857 That is a very nice text.

Answer (score 0):

There's a well-known lemma that a minimal left ideal in a semiprime ring is of the form $Re$ where $e$ is an idempotent. So, it suffices to prove another handy lemma:

> If $f$ is another idempotent and $Re$ is simple, then $Rf+Re=Rg$ for a third idempotent $g$.

*Proof*:
By simplicity, either $Re(1-f)=0$ or $Re(1-f)=Re$.  The first case implies $Re\cap Rf\neq \{0\}$, whence $Re\subseteq Rf$ and $g=f$ works.

In the second case, it easily implies $ef=0$. Set $g=e+f-fe\in Re+Rf$. Routine computation shows $g$ is an idempotent, and by definition $Rg\subseteq Re+Rf$. Finally since $e=eg$ and $f=fg$, we also have $Re+Rf\subseteq Rg$, proving equality $Rg=Re+Rf$. $\square$

With the lemma shown, you can just apply induction to show that a f.g. semisimple left ideal $I$, which must be a direct sum of finitely many simple left ideals of the form $Re$ with $e$ idempotent, will be of the form $Rg$ for some idempotent.